# Is the tag [magic-missile] necessary?

Tags: discussion, tags

I think the tag [magic-missile](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-missile) is a little too precise and doesn't add anything. Are tags like these really necessary and should we keep using them?

Answer (score 5):

No.  It is goofy and unhelpful.  Not every noun in a question should be a tag, especially in the age of search.

However, here on RPG.SE tags are a crowdsourced emergent folksonomy.  If you detest it, remove it from the question(s) where it appears and it should eventually get reaped. Question askers may disagree and re-add it, in which case we'll let it ride - the modclique(tm) tries to be as hands off as possible and let the community run.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to propose a heuristic for which tags we should keep and which ones we should discard. Here goes:

1. Would you ever seek an expert on `<tag>` ?
2. Would you ever call yourself an expert on `<tag>` ?
3. Does the question become ambiguous or unanswerable if you remove  the `<tag>` tag?

I'd say, if the answer to any one of these questions is a *no*, then that tag is probably not necessary.

Comment: I think this fits the intent of the tag system. I see a dissenting voter though: care to share your thoughts? (My own caveat: heuristics tend to only (dis)prove themselves when used, so even one that looks good on paper can turn out to be seriously flawed when it's actually tried. If anyone uses this, it should be always questioning whether it works…)